# Stored procedure in DB2

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have a stored procedure that starts with the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE somename.tablename (IN P_DATE DATE,
                                            OUT P_ROWS_TO_INSERT INTEGER)
```

Can someone please explain the purpose of the IN and OUT parameter calls?

Answer (score 1):

So SQL `OUT` parameter allows the stored procedure to the pass data value back to invoker. `IN` param is param what you adding to your stored procedure.

Basic example:

```
DECLARE
   V_OUT INTEGER;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE SomeName('22.2.2000', V_OUT);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OUT is: ' || V_OUT);
END;
```